# checkstyle to avoid default values?

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

I am using [eclipse-cs](http://eclipse-cs.sourceforge.net/) i.e checkstyle plugin
i am looking for module where it can show warning in case developer assigns the default value which is not required as default
value fot int is 0.

```
public class Test {
  public int size = 0;
}
```

I did not get any module .Any help ?

Comment: Please be aware that requests for offsite tools, libraries and similar are off-topic on StackOverflow. You may want to read http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information and then ask the question on http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Im not sure if it works and how exactly to use it, but you can try with `<module name="MagicNumber"/>`

Comment: Magic number would not work for "int var=0"; only for other values ;o)

Comment: In the sense of understandable code, it seems for me, that `int size = 0;` is must clearer, than just `int size;`

Comment: @AngeloNeuschitzer This is on-topic. Checkstyle questions are by nature closely related to code and are traditionally asked on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for the [ExplicitInitialization](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#ExplicitInitialization) check.